# mapping data flow column pattern type =='decimal' not changing decimal columns

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I'm using a column pattern to catch nulls.  My logic is very simple.

**Matching condition**

```
type=='decimal'
```

**Column name expression**

```
$$
```

**Value expression**

```
coalesce($$,toDecimal(0,38,18))
```

I can't get this to work it simply leaves NULL values in place.  I can however use the expression

```
type!='string' && type!='date'
```

This does change the value of the columns with NULL values to 0.  In my current case this is fine I have strings, dates and decimals but I can see how this is not ideal as I might have integers, doubles or other types and I would not want these to be converted to decimals and the list of && statements becomes quite long.

Can anyone supply details of how I should specify a decimal type or a better workaround if not?  If there is a link to any good references would be helpful too, the [official](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-column-pattern#pattern-matching-expression-values) documentation is not especially specific.

To confirm I am working with decimal values:
[image: showing decimals]

Comment: Are you certain that the incoming columns are indeed being seen as decimals by ADF? Take a look at the incoming values in the inspect or data preview tab and see what data type ADF is seeing that column as.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I knew I was working with Decimals as I explicitly convert them earlier in my pipeline.   Your comment prompted me to confirm in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `typeMatch(type, 'number')` if you want to match all number types.  Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#typematch), other options are:

```
typeMatch(type, 'integral') /* matches short, integer, long */
typeMatch(type, 'fractional') /* matches double, float, decimal */
typeMatch(type, 'datetime') /* matches date, timestamp */
```

Comment: Hi Howard. Thanks for that. This adds real value to the thread. Not exactly what I was looking for at the time but definitely something to bear in mind and a time saver in lots of examples I can think of.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead - Decimal has precision and scale

startsWith(type, 'decimal')

Comment: Hi Kiran so if I get what you are saying a rule `type =='decmial(10,2)' ` and `type=='decimal(38,18)'` would have different results.  Definitely the sort of nuance I would expect to see in documentation but nowhere to be seen.  I'll try your suggestion and report back with results.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I stumbled in the same issue and I fixed it by just assigning the precision and scale like this `type=='decimal(38,20)'` just note that the arguments go like (scale, precision). This worked for me.

Comment: Hi, gmonster1st. The issue with adding the precision and scale is that if a column arrives with a different scale it won't select other columns of the decimal type that don't conform to these values `type=='decimal(38,20)'` would ignore decimal(18,9). This was my problem to begin with.